# how to detect execution environment?

Tags: clojure

I would like to have a pair of`db-spec`maps with my database configuration for development and production.

But I can't find an easy way to detect the current execution environment. Need something like `(defn db-spec [] (if (is-dev?) { dev-spec-here } { prod-spec-here }))`.

Maybe it can detect the current lein profile. No matter how I ask to google. Can't find how.

Comment: So... you're trying to come up with a suitable implementation for the `is-dev?` function to give your desired behavior? If so, I think you need to give a little more details about how this application is intended to be deployed and run.

Comment: Hi @Alex basically if you're in the repl. Anyway I found the solution using java system properties. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13921837/466250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fond of using environment variables for this (which can be set system wide for example in /etc/profile amongst other places). others prefer to pass a -D definition to the JVM

Comment: Great. The -D thing was perfect. At lein dev profile added `:jvm-opts ["-Ddev=true"]` then I ask for `(System/getProperty "dev")`. If `nil` then use production configuration. Use development config otherwise

Answer (score 0):

your code is okay, detect it depend your environment, like `hostname`, `IP arrdress`, `global variable` etc.

Comment: can you provide more details?